# C: Print Reverse Linked List

Tags: c, recursion

I'm struggling with what might seem a very simple question about linked lists in C. *Here it goes:*

I need to print a reverse linked list with a space between elements. After printing the last (in this case, first) element I have to break page instead of printing a space. So it would be something as the following:

```
Linked List: [1,2,3,4]
```

```
Expected Output: 4 3 2 1\n
```

I am aware that I have to store information from the first element in order to create a conditional structure to implement what the question asks. However, since I'm using recursion I've got no clue how.

Here's the state of my current function:

```
void print_list(LinkedNode *start)
    if(start == NULL){
        return;
    }
    
    print_list(start->next);
    printf("%d ", start->data);
    return;
```

And here's the struct of the list:

```
typedef struct LinkedNode LinkedNode;
struct LinkedNode {
   int data;
   LinkedNode *next;
};
```

Also note that I cannot use any header besides **stdio.h** and **stdlib.h**.

I almost forgot to mention but this is my first question here so I would really appreciate any tips around.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your recursive solution (at least academically). Is your only problem that you can't figure out how to print a newline on the last emersion from recursion? Hint: Who said this has to the the only function you write? E.g. why not write another function that calls *this* function, then prints a newline afterward. By-definition it will be the after the top-most call to `print_list`. There are other alternatives, but that seems a pretty simple one.

Comment: @WhozCraig just off top of my head, I think that simple solution will create `" \n"` at end with his recursion, not just only one `\n` because space is already printed by recursion.

Comment: @WhozCragi really simple and great tip! It worked! However, I still got a space after the last element. So now it is something as this: 4 3 2 1 \n. And it should be: 4 3 2 1\n. Space is being printed by "%d ". Any clues on how to fix that?

Comment: Just figured it out! Will soon post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Thanks to @Afshin and @WhozCraig!

Solution down below:

```
void print_aux(LinkedNode *start, int aux){
    if(start == NULL){
        return;
    }

    aux++;
    print_aux(start->next, aux);
    aux--;
    if(aux!=0) printf("%d ", start->data);
    else printf("%d", start->data);
    return;
}

void print_list(LinkedNode *start){
    print_aux(start, 0);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple method if you want to end with `\n`, not `" \n"`. There are probably better methods, but I just wanted a quick solution:

```
void print_list(LinkedNode *start, char delim)
{
    if(start == NULL){
        return;
    }
    
    print_list(start->next, ' ');
    printf("%d%c", start->data, delim);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // initialize my_list
    print_list(my_list, '\n');
}
```

Comment: *"There are probably better methods"* - Maybe, but don't sell yourself short; this is a good solution. It doesn't preserve the original single-arg function signature, but it is still interesting and the OP can learn from it (which is the point).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for this positive comment, it was unexpected. :)

Comment: @Afshin The huge issue that I forgot to mention is that I cannot modify the function's arguments. So it should receive only the start of the linked list. Nonetheless I thank you and WhozCraig for doing your best to help me out. :)